# How to use textLocal API with NodeJS and sequelize to send OTP on mobile

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, one-time-password, textlocal

I wanted to send OTP on mobile numbers using textLOcal in nodejs with Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

To make http call use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm

> npm i request request-promise --save

create folder named "services" and create a file for class "TextLocalSMS.js"

```
var httprequest = require('request-promise');

module.exports = class TextLocalSMS {

constructor() {
}

async callApi(METHOD,URL,BODY){
    var options = {
        method: METHOD,
        uri: URL,
        headers:{
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        },
        json:true
    };
    
    let response= await httprequest(options).then((result)=>{
        console.log(`SMS API: ${URL} RESULT =`,result);
        return result; 
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(`SMS API: ${URL} ERROR =`,err.message);
        return err;
    });
    return response;
}

async sendSMS(toNumbers,rawMessage){
    let url = 'https://api.textlocal.in/send/';
    let sender = encodeURIComponent('TXTLCL');
    let encoded_message = encodeURIComponent(rawMessage);
    let body={
        apikey:'API_KEY',
        numbers:toNumbers.join(','),
        sender:sender,
        message:encoded_message
    };
    let result = await callApi('POST',url,body);
    return result;
}

}
```

Now require this file when you want to use it , suppose in app.js

```
var TextLocalSMS = require('./services/TextLocalSMS');

app.get('/demo',async (req,res)=>{

     // add logic for get user's phone nubmer from database here 
     // ...


     let otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
     let text_msg = `MyWebsite.com -  OTP : ${otp} for reset your account password .`;
     let toNumbers = ['918123456789'];
     let smsService = new TextLocalSMS();
     let smsSent = await smsService.sendSMS(toNumbers,text_msg);

     // database query to store OTP with user_id in your database if otp successfully send to user 
     // ...


     return res.json(smsSent);
})
```